# how to define a timeout for a function in c

Tags: c

Im trying to implement a timeout mechanism in c. I want a particular function to execute for 15 seconds.If the execution time exceeds 15 seconds the program should terminate.

Eg:

```
void somefunction()
{
//------------
}
void main()
{
 somefunction();//this function should have execution time of 30 seconds.
 //If it takes more than 30 seconds it should timeout and pop and error.

 }
```

Comment: Is `somefunction()` a willing participant in this timeout, or are you trying to forcefully time it out?

Comment: What OS?  There's no standard c way, but many functions like select explicitly take a timeout parameter

Comment: im trying to forcefully time it out. max it takes 40seconds to execute.but if there is some problem which cannot be interpreted it does not exit.

Comment: Unix..saw some examples but all of them are related with timeout for reading an input

Comment: Run it in a separate thread while waiting on that thread, and then kill it!? That's just from the top of my head.

Comment: Can u please post some links or an example about how to go about with it. Because i havent dealt with threads.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are REALLY trying to solve, because I think you are asking for a solution to a problem where you THINK a timeout is the right solution, but some other solution may be the "right" thing. Terminating a thread that is in the middle of a system call for example, may not work well.

Comment: It's `int main`, mate, not `void main`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've commented that this is to be a forceful timeout and you're on Unix...

1) In initialization, declare a signal handler for the SIGALRM signal. This signal handler will call `longjmp()`.

2) Just prior to entering your function, call `setjmp()` to set the jump point (for `longjmp()`), and install an `alarm()` for your timeout period.

3) If `setjmp()` returns 0, call your somefunction(). If it returns non-zero (you can control that when you call lonjmp), you know that you've timed out.

"man alarm", "man longjmp", "man setjmp", "man signal" for deeper details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest include the "time.h" then write a simple code that looks like this inside your function:

```
#define FUNC_EXEC_TIME 15

void someFunction() {
    if(clock() > FUNC_EXEC_TIME * 1000) return;
    //...
}
```

If you have a many loops in it, just put the above code inside of it.

Comment: I asked if his `somefunction()` was to be a willing participant or not and he said it was not. The reason I asked was to determine if this was a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: @mah He ask for it. I just tell what I knew. If he/she will have another problem, then why worry asking it again?